# ASP.NET Model State validation returning false when everything should be correct

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i have a problem when i try and post my form within an asp.net app.
I have a blogViewModel like this:

```
namespace Dev_bloggr.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateBlogViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Header { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(200)]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        // Navigation property for the user
        [ValidateNever]
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        //Foreign key for the user
        public string UserId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The only required fields are title, header and content.
Within my controller these are my two methods:

```
      public IActionResult UpsertBlog(int? id)
        {
            var blogViewModel = new CreateBlogViewModel();
            
            if (id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return View(blogViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                var blog = _db.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
                blogViewModel.Id = blog.Id;
                blogViewModel.Title = blog.Title;
                blogViewModel.Header = blog.Header;
                blogViewModel.Content = blog.Content;
                blogViewModel.CreatedAt = blog.CreatedAt;
                blogViewModel.UserId = blog.UserId;
                return View(blogViewModel);
            }
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpsertBlog(CreateBlogViewModel blog)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var userId = User.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
                    var blogInfo = new Blog
                    {
                        Title = blog.Title,
                        Header = blog.Header,
                        Content = blog.Content,
                        CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                        UserId = userId // Set the UserId property to associate the Blog with the user.
                    };
                    if (blog.Id == 0 || blog.Id == null)
                    {
                        if (userId != null)
                        {
                            _db.Blogs.Add(blogInfo);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _db.Blogs.Update(blogInfo);

                    }
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }

            return View();
        }
```

When i fill in the blog with correct asp-for and try and post the result the model.IsValid always returns false.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Could you share the error about the ModelState.IsValid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code with the project version asp.net core 6 in Visual Studio 2022, and I don't meet the error like you. I test with the code:

UpsertBlog.cshtml:

```
@model CreateBlogViewModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="UpsertBlog">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Header" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Header" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Header" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CreatedAt" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CreatedAt" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CreatedAt" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml :

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Client-side validation prevents submission until the form is valid. You can read [Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation) to know more

I guess your problem may be caused by missing Client-side validation or  ApplicationUser User , (you can set breakpoint at  ModelState.IsValid to see the result ) like:

[image]

`[ValidateNever]`: Indicates that a property or parameter should be excluded from validation.

From your code ,I see you have added it.  ApplicationUser User should be excluded from validation.

And from [ValidateNeverAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) we know

> Namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation
>
> Assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll
>
> Package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref v6.0.6

**Option 1**.Make the  `[ValidateNever]` attribute  work

Make sure your Package: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` is maintained, you can refer to [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/6.0.16).  And have Namespace in the CreateBlogViewModel class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
```

**Option 2**.If the  `[ValidateNever]` attribute don't work, you can add `?`  manully to  like:

```
public ApplicationUser? User { get; set; }
```

**Option 3**:  you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file
(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).  You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more.

result:

[image]